# Elixir in Emacs: UndefinedFunctionError: module is not available

Tags: emacs, elixir

I have created a mix project and for learning purposes, am putting all my three files in the lib folder: Client1.ex, Client2.ex and MyLibrary.ex.
I have identical code in Client1.ex and Client2.ex

```
defmodule Project.Client1
#nothing
end
IO.puts(inspect(Project.MyLibrary.myFunc()))
```

When I run this in emacs using `alchemist-compile-this-buffer`,the above code works for Client1 but not for Client2. I get the error

```
elixirc /Users/../lib/Client2.ex
lib/Client2.ex:1: warning: redefining module Project.Client2


== Compilation error on file lib/Client2.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Project.MyLibrary.myFunc/0 (module Project.MyLibrary is not available)
    Project.MyLibrary.myFunc()
    lib/Client2.ex:10: (file)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:95: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8
```

Things I have observed:

- Running mix compile works for Client2
- Client2.beam is not created in the lib folder like the others BUT is in the project root folder which contains the lib folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for using Alchemist, let me try to help you with the issues you encountered.

The `alchemist-compile-this-buffer` function is part of `alchemist-compile` module. 
The `alchemist-compile` module runs all compilations with `elixirc` and that always in the `default-directory` where your `current-buffer-file` is. `alchemist-compile` brings functionality to compile on-the-fly single files outside of `mix` based projects. So, `BEAM` files will always lie there where the `default-directory` and the `current-buffer-file` is.

So, in your case and when you create new Elixir project with `mix` you always need to use the `alchemist-mix` module. `alchemist-mix-compile` which runs `mix compile` will run the compilation in context of the Elixir project and will put `BEAM` files where they belongs under the `_builds` directory in your Elixir project root directory.

I hope that explanation helps you.

If you have more questions, please just call me on the #elixir-lang IRC channel on Freenode. You can just drop message, I'm always connected. ;-)

My username is: tonini

Cheers

Samuel

Comment: Just to clarify, my comments are in no way against alchemist.el but my lack of understanding of Emacs :). I think you are doing a great job.

Comment: I feel overwhelmed by IRC.. but I'll try. Do you prefer IRC over Stackoverflow?

Comment: Hi RArabham. I wouldnt recmmend communicate over Stackoverflow. If you have issue you encouter, just open an issue ticket on the Alchemist repository. And for just questions hit my directly on IRC. But sure, if you getting really question you cant find any help on the docs, maybe its a good idea for a Stackoverflow post so other people might get help too. :) Thanks

Comment: Posting it on Stackoverflow for the benefit of others is a great reason. I am not in a hurry so I don't mind posting here. If I need your help desperately, I'll ping you on IRC,Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, Client2.beam was being created by `alchemist-compile-this-buffer` in the project root folder. Since I was hacking around, I can't remember the exact steps but

- I deleted Client2.beam,
- renamed `defmodule Client2` to something like `defmodule Client2_tmp`
- ran `alchemist-compile-this-buffer` again. It worked. Beam file created in lib/
- renamed module back to Client2 and ran `alchemist-compile-this-buffer` again.

Yes, I feel like a pigeon in a B.F Skinner experiment. I expect to come back with another pigeon dance.